# Compiler warning: FS0058: Possible incorrect indentation

Tags: f#, indentation, compiler-warnings

I wrote this code with Visual Studio but when I compile it, it gives me back these warnings:

> *FS0058: Possible incorrect indentation, this token is offside of context started at position 9:80. Try indenting this token further or using standard formatting* .

But if I try to compile it with an OCaml compiler it works.

```
let converti_tempo = (fun x -> if x < 0 then failwith "error" else if x < 1000 then (0, 0, x) else 
let rec m = x % 1000
let s = (x / 1000) % 60
let mm = ((x / 1000) / 60) % 60
in (mm,s ,m ));;
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the first line you have an `else`. This implies that the expression of the `else` is going to be defined on the next line and thus will have to be indented all the way to the else and then a bit more. Code below:

```
let converti_tempo = (fun x -> if x < 0 then failwith "error" else if x < 1000 then (0, 0, x) else 
                                                                                               let rec m = x % 1000
                                                                                               let s = (x / 1000) % 60
                                                                                               let mm = ((x / 1000) / 60) % 60
                                                                                               in (mm,s ,m ));;
```

You could also write it like this:

```
let converti_tempo = (fun x -> if x < 0 then failwith "error" 
                               else if x < 1000 then (0, 0, x) 
                               else
                                  let rec m = x % 1000
                                  let s = (x / 1000) % 60
                                  let mm = ((x / 1000) / 60) % 60
                                  in (mm,s ,m ));;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is a more "idiomatic" way of writing this function

```
let converti_tempo x =
    if x < 0 then
        failwith "error" 
    elif x < 1000 then
        (0, 0, x)
    else
        let m = x % 1000
        let s = x / 1000 % 60
        let mm = x / 1000 / 60 % 60
        (mm, s, m)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this compiler warning was caused by one of my "let"s not being properly aligned. Make sure all of your function declarations start at the very start of each new line.